# iPod Touch file structure: where should I put a song?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ssh, music, ipod-touch

I have ssh to and from my ipod.  Now I need to know the file structure so that I can manipulate it without itunes (ie wirelessly)

Where would one, for example, put a song file and what files would I have to update and how in order to be able listen in itunes?

Comment: I believe that the music is located in: `var/mobile/media/music ` however, you will probably need a third party media player such as Dtunes because the Ipod has a database that you would have to manually update every time you copy a file. - Not done as an answer because I am not 100% sure as it has been over a year since I saw a jailbroken Ipod. Tell me if it works and I will write as answer.

Comment: Do you have any idea what kind of database?  or what it's called?  I have bash and I'm not afraid to use it.  is it SQL by any chance?

Comment: no, it's not SQL but proprietary, and what's more you won't be able to edit it manually either because of the hashing functions apple put in to basically stop people from updating their iphones/ipods without using itunes. Luckily, there are many open-source projects which have reverse-engineered the function, so your best bet is to use one of them. Check out any linux project which offers an ipod interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in this article:

http://lifehacker.com/388785/sync-your-iphone-wirelessly-in-linux

It does technically refer to linux while you have a mac, but I'm pretty sure it's possible to get most or all of those thing to run under snow leopard.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Just to update on the latest iOS the music is stored in a SQLite3 DB (MediaLibrary.sqlitedb) and you can add songs but it will take a while to add even one with some tags.